# OpenGL in python slowed down by glCheckError calls

Tags: python, performance, opengl, optimization, glsl

I'm attempting to make some performance optimizations on this fractal rendering code I found: https://github.com/HackerPoet/PySpace

When rendering certain fractals, I get decent performance at medium resolutions (~50fps at 720p). However, once the geometry gets slightly more complex it completely drops to about 2 fps. From what I can gather from using cProfile, this is due to a large amount of long calls to glCheckError (picture below.) Since this is never called in the code itself, I'm led to believe that something about the geometry is causing errors that aren't being handled properly when trying to draw the object. I'm not sure if this is the case, though. Any ideas for how I could go about finding the exact culprit?

Here's the profiler output (recorded over 20 frames to avoid print spamming) for a fast fractal and a slower one:

[image: Profile of 20 frames for a "fast" running fractal]

[image: Profile of 20 frames for a slow running fractal]

Comment: The [documentation](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ctypes/using.html) for PyOpenGL says it always calls `glCheckError`, so it isn't indicative of an error. The time for checking errors seems consistent at `0.010`. There are simply more GL calls happening, about 13 times as many.

Comment: Thanks for the link, somehow missed that in the documentation. 10ms seems like a pretty long time to check for an error though, especially since there are none AFAIK. There's also other GL calls that increase in frequency, virtually all of them in fact since the geometry is more complex. However, these don't seem to affect frame rendering times nearly as much. Do you think there would be anything to be gained by replacing the error checking function by my own as described in the documentation? It seems highly unlikely that I could write anything more efficient than already exists...

Answer (score 1):

The pyOpenGL functions to get OpenGL errors are **glGetError**, and **gluErrorString**
Here is an example function that gets an error string and prints it

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *

def opengl_error_check():
    error = glGetError()
    if error != GL_NO_ERROR:
        print("OPENGL_ERROR: ", gluErrorString(error))
```

By moving the call to an error checking function, you can
quickly bisect the OpenGL calls to find the line that is causing the error. 
Often the call that caused the error is more telling than the error itself, since there are only a few possible OpenGL error codes.

Once you have your program debugged you may want to disable error checking since it is a little expensive. It is on by default to make pyOpenGL more beginner friendly.
To disable error checking in PyOpenGL you need to set the `OpenGL.ERROR_CHECKING`
flag to `False`

```py
import OpenGL
OpenGL.ERROR_CHECKING = False
from OpenGL.GL import *
```